# Can't install app com.android.mms on android (INSTALL_FAILED_DUPLICATE_PERMISSION)

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-permissions

This is in the border of programming, so please delete the question if it's not correct posting it.

Question is regarding the Android 5.0 Lollipop.

Basically I've installed the "Messaging" app (com.android.mms) from inside another program (hide it pro). It's an older version of the android messaging. Then my Samsung s5 broke and I had to restore all apps into another similar Samsung. When trying to install the messaging app again (from inside or outside hide it pro) it fails with the error -505. Searching on the net I ended up by installing the android sdk and use adb to see if I could solve the issue. No luck: if I try to uninstall the app (which doesn't exist on the new phone) I get the error DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR.

```
$ adb uninstall /c/mfg/sms.apk
* daemon not running. starting it now o
* daemon started successfully *
Failure [DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR]
```

If I try to install the app via adb I get the following result:

```
$ adb install /c/mfg/sms.apk
3439 KB/s (2078237 bytes in 0.590s)
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/sms.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_DUPLICATE_PERMISSION          
perm=android.permission.MMS_SEND_OUTBOX_MSG pkg=com.android.mms]
```

I don't have the application on the phone, I can't put it to work and I can't get rid of the permissions. There's no way to uninstall on the phone since the app is not there and it won't let itself be installed. It doesn't appear on the Application Manager under "downloaded" or anywhere else.

My question is: is there no way to wipe out the permissions WITHOUT having the application? What I wanted was an app that allowed me to delete the permissions, regardless of having the app or not. The phone is not rooted at the moment but if needed I can root it to solve the issue if it helps. Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've finally found the issue. Thanks Manish and iagocanalejas for the suggestions.
It seems that something changed on the permissions system on android 5.0 (as part of one of the updates). It didn't happen before, but now if two packages from different applications ask for the same permission (in this case android.permission.MMS_SEND_OUTBOX_MSG pkg=com.android.mms), it won't let the second application install.
This behavior is new and didn't happen on previous versions of Lollipop. Flashing a newer version of the OS on my phone clearly didn't solve the issue (original was G900FXXU1BNL9 and I've finished with G900FXXU1BOD3). If anything, only made it worse since this behavior seems to have come to stay.

The solution was to root the phone, install Titanium Backup, and (after backing up everything) REMOVING with help of Titanium Backup the "Messages" application which on the Samsung replaces the standard "Messaging" android app.

Titanium backup was needed because "Messages" is considered as a system application and therefore couldn't be removed normally. No SMS messages were lost by removing "Messages". It was necessary to reboot the phone after removing "Messages" so that "Messaging" could be installed, but finally, after 2 weeks of effort, it could be done.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to uninstall using application package? This should delete any data/cache associated with application.

```
$ adb uninstall com.android.mms
```

Install the application after this as usual:

```
$ adb install /c/mfg/sms.apk
```

Comment: Same result: I issue "$adb uninstall com.android.mms"
and get  "Failure [DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR]"

Comment: Do you have root shell? I'd also try: rm -rf /data/data/com.android.mms

Comment: Phone is not rooted at the moment (no su) but I definitely will root to try and post here if it works later. Thanks.

Comment: So i've rooted,  got su permission, removed directory and still the same error. Is there any file where permissions are written that I could edit?

Comment: I've been investigating and it seems that samsung's messages application is also called com.android.mms. I don't know if it was like that before, but using the stock application name for a custom application really makes things confusing. If I find more I'll write here.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on  your  manifest and see  if u have  duplicated rows